# Closed operations on regular languages

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let x be a language over an alphabet,

INSERT(x) is the set of all strings obtained by adding exactly one more character into any one of the strings in x.

INSERT(x) = { azb : a,b ∈ ∑* and ab ∈ L and z ∈ ∑. }

Why is the set of regular languages closed under the INSERT operation?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: start with an automaton (NFA) for $L$, and try to build a NFA for INSERT($L$).

Answer (score 0):

Since the given language is regular therefore, there exist some finite automaton (NFA/DFA). Now the insert operation inserts just a symbol into any one of the words of the language. Now modify the finite automaton such that introduce a new state and 2 new transitions at the insertion point then you will have a new finite automaton.

Pictorially it is much easier to explain.